# Using AlertDialog style of Kitkat on Lollipop based phones

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-alertdialog, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the same app running perfectly on both Lollipop based android phone as well as a Jellybean based android phone. However the alert dialog styles ( default) are not the same, and the dialog appear ugly in Lollipop phones.

A simple example:

**In Jellybean based phone :**

[image: In Jellybean based phone]

**In Lollipop based phone :**

[image: In Lollipop based phone]

Is it possible for me to use the alert dialog styles of older Android OS on my Lollipop based phones?

How to do this in the app programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the Dialog's theme by setting the second constructor parameter of your `AlertDialog` or `AlertDialog.Builder` to `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). However, it shows in the code that ALertDailog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT is deprecated. This still works.. but will it cause any problems?

Comment: It seems to be deprecated since API 23, so it won't cause any problems in near future.

Answer (score 5):

If you want Lollipop Dialog into your Pre-Lollipop Device, then you have to use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` instead of `android.app.AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

---

And if you want to use Pre-Lollipop AlertDialog into Lollipop Device, then you have to use following themes:

- `AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL`
- `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`
- `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`
- `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`
- `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`

and use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, theme);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). However, it shows in the code that ALertDailog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT is deprecated. This still works.. but will it cause any problems?

Comment: This is deprecated but, Not causing any issue.

Comment: @RohitSuthar So what should we use instead of it

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Hope it OK

Comment: Thank you so much :). However, it shows in the code that ALertDailog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT is deprecated. This still works.. but will it cause any problems?

Comment: I dont see it is deprecated in my code. It still OK